# how to send files to other people in small nodejs chat app

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, chat

I have made a small chat app with nodejs and now i'm trying to make it possible, if two people are chatting, that they can also send small files to each other.

I have just started learning node, so it's a bit confusing for me. I'm trying to make this work but i'm not even sure how am i supposed to do it.

So any help is welcome :)

btw var file is a file from the input type=file.

Here's my code:

index.js

```
    var express = require("express");
    var app = express();
    var fs = require("fs");
    var port = 8888;


        // fs.readFile(sendFile, function (err, data) {
        //   if (err) {
        //           return console.error(err);
        //   }
        //   console.log("Asynchronous read: " + data.toString());
        // });

    app.set('views', __dirname + '/tpl');
    app.set('view engine', "jade");
    app.engine('jade', require('jade').__express);
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

    app.get("/", function(req, res){
        res.render("page");
    });

    var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(port));

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.emit('message', { message: 'Welcome to the chat :)' });
        socket.on('send', function (data) {
            io.sockets.emit('message', data);
        });
    });

    io.sockets.on('sendFile', function(data){
        socket.emit('getFile',data)
    });
```

chat.js

```
        window.onload = function() {

            var messages = [];
            var socket = io.connect('http://'+location.host);
            var field = document.getElementById("field");
            var sendButton = document.getElementById("send");
            var content = document.getElementById("content");
            var name = document.getElementById("name");
            var file = document.getElementById("file").files;


        // file.onchange = function(e) {
        //  var file = document.getElementById("file").files;
        //  console.log(file);
        // }

            socket.on('message', function (data) {
                if(data.message) {
                    messages.push(data);
                    var html = '';
                    for(var i=0; i<messages.length; i++) {
                        html += '<b>' + (messages[i].username ? messages[i].username : 'Server') + ': </b>';
                        html += messages[i].message + '<br />';
                    }
                    content.innerHTML = html;
                } else {
                    console.log("There is a problem:", data);
                }
            });

            socket.on('getFile', function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });


            sendButton.onclick = sendMessage = function() {
                if(name.value == "") {
                    alert("Please type your name!");
                } else {
                    socket.emit('sendFile', file);
                    var text = field.value;
                    socket.emit('send', { message: text, username: name.value });
                    field.value = "";
                }
            };

            field.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
                if(e.keyCode == 13) {
                    sendMessage();
                }
        });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this is not answer using your code but you can Make it easy by using [delivery module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/delivery)

Bidirectional File Transfers For Node.js via Socket.IO, See code on [Github Link](https://github.com/liamks/Delivery.js)